# Azure Web Apps Application only starts the second time

Tags: spring-boot, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a Spring Boot application set up in Azure Web Apps.
There is the weirdest thing that the application manages to start based on the logs but it will continue with the "warm up" logs until it times out:

```
2023-06-12T18:55:39.505418276Z 2023-06-12T18:55:39.505Z  INFO 8 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.w.s.WelcomePageHandlerMapping    : Adding welcome page: class path resource [static/index.html]
2023-06-12T18:55:42.270061250Z 2023-06-12T18:55:42.269Z  INFO 8 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2023-06-12T18:55:42.346119751Z 2023-06-12T18:55:42.345Z  INFO 8 --- [           main] com.demo.DemoApplication        : Started DemoApplication in 83.118 seconds (process running for 89.173)
2023-06-12T18:58:04.385Z ERROR - Container XXXXX_2_96097e99 for site XXXXX did not start within expected time limit. Elapsed time = 230.8177376 sec
2023-06-12T18:58:05.033Z ERROR - Container XXXXX_2_96097e99 didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8080, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
```

Then, after it times out, whenever I try to call any endpoint, it starts again the image but this time it manages to start up.
So at the end it does work, but still it's an annoying bug, if anyone has a suggestion that would be greatly appreciated!

Edits:
My deployment configuration is quite basic, and as it works the second time, I'm not sure it could cause the issue:
[image]

Comment: Are you using docker?

Comment: Yes I am, I use GH Actions to build and upload and deploy the image to ACR. Which scripts were generated by Azure.

Answer (score 0):

I have created spring boot application at deployed into ACR (Azure container repository) from IntelliJ.

- The app is running successful.

[image]

- Then, I have pushed into Docker Successfully.

[image]

- Here, I have created app service and publish from **Docker**.

[image]

- Here, I given the Azure container registry details.

[image]

- I can run my application in local from container.

[image]

- After deploying into app service also I can be able to run the application.

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is similar to what I have only, I use GH Actions to build and upload and deploy the image to ACR. Which scripts were generated by Azure.

Comment: Great to hear @Elemer Botos, please check this [link](https://www.ntweekly.com/2021/07/07/build-a-docker-image-and-push-it-to-acr-using-github-actions/) for your above requirement.

Comment: @SPT yes, thank you, it did not solve my problem

Comment: @ElemérBotos, Can you please provide the container logs for more inforamtion. Azure Web Apps provides a way to access and view the container logs, which can provide additional details about what might be causing the container to fail to respond.